# Generating data from exponential distribution by incorporating correlation between two random variables

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, distribution, correlation

Suppose `X~exp(.67)` , `Y~exp(.45)` and `Z~exp(.8)`. Now `X` is correlated with `Y` with a correlation coefficient -0.6. Again, `X` is correlated with `Z` with a correlation coefficient -0.6. How can I incorporate this correlations to generate random variables `X`, `Y` and `Z`? I know if there were no correlation among them, then I could simply generate data by `X <- rexp(n=10, rate=.67)`, `Y <- rexp(10, .45)` and `Z <- rexp(10, .8)`.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can use the *Iman and Conover method* from the package `mc2d`.

First, create your settings. I have assumed that Y and Z are uncorrelated, given the absence of a stated correlation above. (If they are not, just change the correlation matrix accordingly.)

```
library(mc2d)
x1 <- rexp(n = 1000, rate = 0.67)
x2 <- rexp(n = 1000, rate = 0.45)
x3 <- rexp(n = 1000, rate = 0.8)
mat <- cbind(x1, x2, x3)
corr <- matrix(c(1, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, 1, 0, -0.6, 0, 1), ncol=3)
```

We can now test the actual correlations of the random samples ... that all seem independent, as expected.

```
cor(mat, method="spearman")
```

... which generates:

```
            x1         x2         x3
x1  1.00000000 0.01602557 -0.0493488
x2  0.01602557 1.00000000  0.0124209
x3 -0.04934880 0.01242090  1.0000000
```

We now apply the *Iman and Conover method* to the data.

```
matc <- cornode(mat, target=corr, result=TRUE)
```

Doing so yields the following correlations:

```
Spearman Rank Correlation Post Function
           x1          x2          x3
x1  1.0000000 -0.59385975 -0.56201396
x2 -0.5938597  1.00000000 -0.04115543
x3 -0.5620140 -0.04115543  1.00000000
```

Finally, by running `head(matc)`, we see the initial rows of your revised sample:

```
             x1        x2         x3
[1,]  1.1375395 0.3081750 2.26850817
[2,]  2.9387996 0.4434207 0.08940867
[3,]  1.0918648 0.4175625 2.29498679
[4,] 10.0273879 1.1478072 0.16099230
[5,]  1.5093832 0.4023230 2.57870672
[6,]  0.9474039 2.1134685 0.95268424
```